# Java and the word "new"

Tags: java

If I have two classes A and B as follows :

**class A**:

```
class A{
   int i;
   A(int j){
       i=j;
   }
}
```

**class B**:

```
class B{
    A a;
    B(A a){
        this.a=a;
    }
 }
```

Then if I have a program that has the following statement:

```
A a = new A(5);
B b = new B(a);
```

my question is:

Am I going to have two different objects `a` and `b.a`, which will have the same value of `i`, or is my `b.a` object just pointing to the object `a` and if I change the value of `a.i`, then the value of `b.a.i` will also change?

Comment: Thank you all, you answears were very very helpful!!!!

Comment: ...then it would be good if you accept one of them as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
B b = new B(a);
```

the line

```
this.a = a;
```

will copy the **reference** of the `A` instance. In other words, both `a` and `b.a` will *refer* to the same location in memory, where the `A` instance is stored.

They are different ways to access to the same object. So, if you change one object through one of those variables, the same object will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

There will be one `A` object and two pointer `a` and `a.b` to that object. You can alter the state of that object by using those two references `a` and `b.a`.

Answer (score 1):

**Java is pass by value!**

In this case value of the reference pointing to the Object is passed. So you have two references pointing to same instance of Object A.

Answer (score 0):

Same object and two pointers pointing to same object as java is **pass by value**

```
System.out.println(a.i+"--------"+a.hashCode());
    System.out.println(b.a.i+"------"+b.a.hashCode());
```

these above two lines will print the same values. as object is same.

Answer (score 0):

There will be an instance of A, it holds an integer.

And there will be an instance of B. It receives a reference (pointer) to A.

So accessing b.a.i is going to change the integer in the instance of A.

Primitives are copied by value. For classes, the pointer to the object is copied by value.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java references are passed by value, the object pointed to by **a** and **b.a** is the exact same one, meaning that changing one 'value' changes both. So if you call a cup a tumbler and I call it a container if I put something water in it the water is in that same utensil that you call 'tumbler' and I call 'container.' Hope this example helps.